# Using Bamboo to build Subversion/Maven project that defines parent POM(s)

Tags: svn, maven, bamboo

I have a complex project structure that goes something like this:

```
- root (no pom)
     - parent(parent pom.xml)
     + project A (pom.xml)
     + project B (pom.xml)
     - project C (pom.xml)
         - subproject 1 (pom.xml)
         - subproject 2 (pom.xml)
     + project N (pom.xml)
```

I need to build `subproject 2` using Bamboo server. I use Bamboo to checkout `subproject 2` code but when I run `mvn install` on that it fails with "Non-resolvable parent POM" message.

The build runs fine when all the code is in the single location. I don't want to checkout code on `root` level since there are tons of projects that I don't want to check out (in my example that would be projects A, B, N and subproject 1)

I attempted to check out code 3 times for parent, project C/pom and subproject 2 but the code is placed onto separate directories with no relation to each other so there's not much help there

P.S.
I'm using no modules, though I did try it with modules and it made no difference. I'm not posting the actual POMs since these are very trivial, basically child pom has `parent` element and that's all relation there is.

All upstream projects are deployed to both local and remote repos

Comment: Is this a multi-module build where using parent in project-A, subproject 1 etc. ?

Comment: Not really - this is limited to child pom pointing to the parent pom. In my case it is sub2.pom->projC.pm->../parent.pom

Comment: Are your other projects (eg. A, and sub 1) already built somewhere else ?

Comment: Yes, other projects are already deployed to maven

Comment: Your problem might be a setting in Bamboo that restricts it to use a private repository for each project. I know that is possible in Jenkins/hudson and can break things like this..

Answer (score 2):

mvn will look for dependencies in three places, in a relative path on the local file system, cached in the m2 repo on your local machine, or in an external repo.  If you install all the dependencies on a repo that bamboo can access, your build will probably work.

To test this, on your local machine, can you do a mvn install from the root directory (placing all the dependencies in the m2 repo on your machine), and then checkout subproject2 in a separate directory and then mvn install subproject2?

If that works, then the dependencies of subproject 2 need to be in a maven repo that bamboo can access.  Deploy them using something like [artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) before doing mvn install with bamboo.

Comment: What do you mean by "entire tree"? On my local machine I can build this project without any problem. I think the problem with Bamboo is that it pulls 3 projects into unrelated, separate directories, then when a build starts it can't find parent POMs

Comment: Just to reiterate - all upward dependencies are already deployed to repo yet when Bamboo attempts to execute "mvn install" on subproject it complains that parent dependency is missing

Comment: Could you post the pom and the exact error message?  Better yet would be to post the effective pom.  If everything can be resolved, building a sub module should work.

Comment: There's no sub module per say. I have a child pom referencing a parent pom which in the turn references a global parent pom

Comment: Actually even adding modules to the parent project will not fix it. I still get the same error: "Non-resolvable parent POM" when attempting to build from the child level

Comment: Can you reproduce this on your local machine using the steps I described above?

Comment: You can deploy the file using something like `mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.company -DartifactId=artifact -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=pom -Dfile=path/to.pom -DrepositoryId=snapshots -Durl=http://your-repo/repo`

Comment: As I mentioned in my other comment all the upstream dependencies are deployed to repo and everything builds just fine on the local machine but not in Bamboo

Comment: That is local and remote repos. The way I see it - Bamboo pulls out child source from SVN. Then when you perform the build Maven cannot reference parent POM since it is simply not there on the disk

Answer (score 1):

We have a very similar project structure, and I just verified that I'm able to create a Jenkins job that only checks out the equivalent of `subproject1` and builds it with `mvn -U clean install`.  I have no access to a Bamboo instance, but both Jenkins and Bamboo just invoke Maven under the hood, so there should be no difference here.

The other option that works, as you mentioned, is to checkout the entire repository, (or directory containing root and all modules) and run `mvn -U clean install -pl subproject1 -am` on the parent POM.

**To help you with this, we really need more information.**  You mentioned in one of your comments that "all [upstream] dependencies are already deployed to repo".  Do you mean your local repository (i.e. .m2/repository)?  You should double check that this directory contains all of the parent POMs. Are you resolving all artifacts from a proxy (i.e. Artifactory/Nexus)?  If so, also check that the POMs are available there.

Your current structure diagram doesn't show the location of the POMs.  I assume you've got it setup correctly, but I have seen cases where people put child modules in strange locations, which can cause problems.  The [relative locations of the POMs matter](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-parent.html) (unless you do some customization). Could you run `tree` on the root and sanitize the output so that we know exactly where your POMs are in relation to one another? For example:

```
parentProject
|-- projectA
|   |-- pom.xml
|
|-- projectB
|   |-- pom.xml
|   |
|   |-- subProject1
|   |   |-- pom.xml
|   |    
|   |-- subProject2
|       |-- pom.xml
|
|-- pom.xml
```

Lastly, could you navigate to the child project/module you're attempting to build and post the output of `mvn help:effective-pom`?

Comment: In my (original) diagram every node (and leaf) contains pom.xml. There's no pom.xml in the very top level, as you see there's "parent" directory on the same level as A and B and from the A, B, C... N it is referred as "../parent". All upstream projects are deployed in both local and remote repos

Answer (score 0):

Each of the maven modules should be self contained, using relative links that talk about ../parent breaks this design.

Try and explicitly define the parents by GAV properties, and then ensure these poms are `install`ed in your local maven repo and you will be able to build sub projects.

We run a 15 module build down 3 levels and this is all possible.

The only issue you have is when you bump versions, you will have to kick off an install of the root pom file to boostrap the resolution process.